# an advise to fix the error illegalStateException inside if statement

Tags: java, primes

Im writing an application that print the set of prime numbers with a given length. this is an application for a general length for example all the numbers form 1 to 100

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Sieve
{
    private int number;

    public Sieve (int maxPrime)
    {
        number = maxPrime;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getPrimes()
    {
        Set<Integer> setNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();


        for(int i=2; i<=number; i++)
        {
            setNumbers.add(i);
        }

        Iterator<Integer> iter = setNumbers.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            int number1 = iter.next();

            for( int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++ )
            {
                if( number1 % i == 0)
                {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }

        } 
        return setNumbers;
    }
}
```

the part that is giving me an error is the part inside of the if statement. it says illegalStateException. can someone help me to figure it out how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `remove` method more than once between `next`.  From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29):

> "IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called,
>   or the remove method has already been called after the last call to
>   the next method"

It should be:

```
bool isComposite = false;

for( int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number1); i++ )
{
    if( number1 % i == 0)
    {
        isComposite = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isComposite)
{
    iter.remove();
}
```

The algorithm bug is that you're going up to the square root of `number` (the maximum possible prime to consider) rather than the root of `number1`, the current prime you're considering.  That means you'll exclude 2 because it's less than sqrt(100) and is a multiple of 2.

This is a sign you should use better variable names.

Comment: this is good, but one little problem is that i dont get the number 2,3,5,7 which are also prime numbers.

Comment: add this code before if(isPrime):-   if(number1 == 1 || number1== 2 || number1== 3){
    isPrime=false;
  }

Comment: @Nishant, that's a kludge.  There is nothing special about 3.

Comment: @Nishant - what an awful idea.  He needs to find the real cause of the problem, not add some random hack to make it produce the right answer.